# VBA - Insert cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know the code for inserting specified cells ranges below. For example, if I have a table with values from A2:F2, I want to create a code, which inserts a row below (i.e. A3:F3) and so on as and when the procedure is run. I want to insert rows only for specified range, not full row.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub InsertCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FirstHeaderCell As Range
    Dim LastHeaderCell As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1") 'change here to your needs
    Set FirstHeaderCell = ws.Range("A2") 'change here to your needs
    Set LastHeaderCell = ws.Range("C2") 'change here to your needs
    
    With ws
        LastRow = FirstHeaderCell.Rows.End(xlDown).Row + 1
        .Range(.Cells(LastRow, FirstHeaderCell.Column), .Cells(LastRow, LastHeaderCell.Column)).Insert xlShiftDown
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

You may not have merged cells under your table.